# performance degradation when switching from pandas column concatenation to using apply on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe holding data from a csv file. I want to concatenate few columns, I first hardcoded that with simple pandas column concatenation, then I refactored the code to be more general, but I got penalized severely in terms of run time, here are the two versions of the concatenation and their timings:

```
    t0 = time.time()
    cleaned_data_set1 = data_set.col1.map(str)+" "+data_set.col2.map(str)+ " " + data_set.col3.map(str)
    t1 = time.time()

    print t1-t0
    listOfObjectAttributeNames = ["col1","col2","col3"]
    t0 = time.time()
    cleaned_data_set = data_set.apply(lambda x: " ".join([str(el) for el in x[listOfObjectAttributeNames]]), axis=1)
    t1 = time.time()
```

here is the execution time respectively:

```
1.20745110512
171.689060926
```

How can I improve the run time of the second version?

Comment: Not an answer but it is worth to mention that you'd better use `timeit` to measure execution time

Comment: The first version is the vectorized approach, this is always the best approach, because it is faster. The second version is a non-vectorized approach, you optimize it by using version one.

Comment: @firelynx , thanks for helping, I would like to use the first version, but I am still failing to specify the column names dynamically, can you help with that?

Comment: What are the dtypes of col1 through to col3? if they are str already you can just do: `cleaned_data_set1 = data_set.col1+" "+data_set.col2 " " + data_set.col3`

Comment: @EdChum some of the cells are NaN, I am ensuring they are str before carrying on. But now, I am looking for how to keep the vectorized version and specify dynamically the column names.

Comment: Do you want to keep the `NaN` or replace them with blank string values? personally I'd get the dtype to what you want and then use simple arithmetic operators like my previous comment

Comment: @EdChum I am mapping NaN to empty string. I did use the simple arithmetic operation, but I need to generalize it.

Comment: Generally using `apply` should be avoided it's essentially a for loop and not vectorised, it would be better to write a func that performed vectorised operations rather than using `apply` at all

Comment: @MedAli Just make `data_set.col1.map(str)` into `data_set['col1'].map(str)`

Comment: @firelynx , thanks I've done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to keep the vectorized version and generalize the operation as follows:

```
        t0 = time.time()

        listOfObjectAttributeNames = ["col1","col2","col3"]

        cleaned_data_set = ""
        for i in listOfObjectAttributeNames:
            cleaned_data_set = cleaned_data_set + data_set[i].map(str)

        t1 = time.time()

        print t1 - t0
```

run time result:

```
 1.04347801208
```